# NSPredicate in Realm - searching for any item from an array in results

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have a Realm database with a list of places, which each have a list of placeTypes. I'd like to be able to use a predicate query, such as -

```
let searchKey = "hotel"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN placeTypes", searchKey)
```

but this doesn't work when I want to match multiple search keys. My solution so far is to use NSCompoundPredicate -

```
let searchKeys = ["hotel", "cafe", "bar"]
let predicates: [NSPredicate] = searchKeys.map { NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN placeTypes", $0) }
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```

which is all well & good & does work, but I have a feeling that this can't be particularly efficient for large tables, & it'd be nice to get it into a single predicate anyway.

If anyone has any ideas how this could be done, I'd be grateful - no amount of searching on SO has found a similar question.

Comment: Table schema please?

Answer (score 0):

It might be more efficient to break down the items to categories like hotels, restaurant etc this way you only search in respective categories